# What is the point of undefined variable in javascript module pattern

Tags: design-patterns, javascript, commonjs

I come across the following javascript module pattern and like it very much, but, why the use of `undefined` in the argument?

```
(function(window, document, undefined){

    'use strict';

    var MyWidget = function(){

        if (!(this instanceof MyWidget)) {
            var test = new MyWidget();
            return test.init.call(test, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
        }

      var firstPrivateVar = 'aa',
          secondPrivateVar = 'bb';

      this.init = function(options){
        console.log('MyWidget.init', options);
        return true;
      };

      this.setStuff = function(){

      };

    };

    window.MyWidget = MyWidget;

})(window, document);
```

Comment: why pass in window and document?? are they not always accessible?

Answer (score 2):

In ECMAScript 3 the developer had the right to use the undefined keyword as a variable i.e. it was mutable. So if I were to write

```
undefined = true;
```

the value of undefined would be true and it would lose its true meaning. 
In this above mentioned scenario, we are passing the window object, the document object and there is no third parameter. so this means that in `function(window, document, undefined)`, the undefined variable will be actually undefined as we are not passing any parameter to it.

According to ECMAScript5, this undefined in not mutable any more

Answer (score 1):

`undefined` can be overwritten in some browsers. This fixes the problem in your scope by redefining `undefined` to the value of a non-existent parameter.